# How to clip an SVG plot?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg.js

My SVG element is setup as this:

```
svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + chartView.displayWidth + " " + chartView.displayHeight);
```

inside I'm drawing some plots. Is there a way to create a "see through window" inside which I can see my plots?

I tried using:

```
svg.append("clipPath").append("rect")
                    .attr("x", 10)
                     .attr("y", 10)
                    .attr("width", 50)
                   .attr("height", 100);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks, how to do it actually? can I set an svg.attr?

Comment: @RobertLongson actually it's gonna be a rect so "clip-rect" ?

Comment: @RobertLongson see my edit

Comment: I thought "svg.append" expressed the intent of "set a clip-path on the element I want to clip". Am I wrong?

Comment: so how can I set the clipPath to my svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments you would use a ClipPath.
You already tried to create one using `append`. As far as I know, this is `D3.js` or `jQuery` syntax. But you tagged `svg.js`.
In svg.js you would do it like this:

```
svg.viewbox(0, 0, chartView.displayWidth, chartView.displayHeight);

var plot = svg.path('your plots path data').stroke('#000')

var clipper = svg.rect(50, 100).move(10, 10)

// to clip the whole svg use svg instead of plot
plot.clipWith(clipper)
```

If you use D3.js you are almost there.
You already created the clippath. You now have to give it an id, and reference this id in your plot.

```
var clip = svg.append("clipPath").attr("id", "clipper");
clip.append("rect").attr("x", 10)
                   .attr("y", 10)
                   .attr("width", 50)
                   .attr("height", 100);

yourplot.attr("clip-path", "url(#clipper)")
```

If you want to clip the whole svg with your rect, use `svg.attr(...)` instead of `yourplot.attr(...)`

Make sure to read the svg specification or some tutorial about clipPaths

Comment: In refer to my question, "yourPlot" should be "svg". Don't forget semicolons in your JavaScript answers. Seems silly, but in Javascript a missing semicolon is a PITA to debug. Ok it works.. Answer accepted

Comment: not necessarily. If you want to window each indivudial plot, you have to do it as I wrote. You never should edit an answer without giving a note what you changed and why. The svg.js version now doenst fit the d3 version. Will change it accordingly

Comment: The SVG has a viewBox on it so you're unlikely to get the result you expect if you put a clipPath on the `<svg>` element itself.